# What is a red dot in markdown file?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, visual-studio-code, markdown

I use vscode to edit my markdown file, picture as below is a part of my markdown file

[image]

But when I pushed it to my origin branch, it shown as this picture when I view it on github

[image]

In edit mode on github, the � character becomes to a red dot, like :

[image]

And there is no "utf8 with bom" option in vscode my encoding list. But when I go to "View -> toggle controller character ", my markdown file shows something different like :

[image]

I've tried search it , and most of the answer is about the "utf8 without bom" thing. But seems vscode use "utf8 without bom" as default, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What's your Github repo?

Comment: You can view it on https://github.com/chenxinlong/alg/blob/master/recursion/recursion.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer in the issues of vscode :  [Using IME with markdown preview enabled, press ESC/BACKSPACE leads in control characters](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37114)

Chrome render this red dot when there's a control character in your file. In vscode, it is invisiable when you doesn't enable `editor.renderControlCharacters`.

So you should enable `editor.renderControlCharacters` and remove it before you push it to github.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be nothing, or at least when I click on the "Raw" button:

[image: Raw document]

It might be something wrong with your configuration of Visual Studio Code or it may be a keyboard problem:

At the bottom of the Visual Studio Code editor, could you try setting your encoding to `UTF-8`?

[image: Where the UTF-8 button is on Visual Studio Code]

When you click on it, it should show the following two options (Reopen with Encoding and Save with Encoding):

[image: Options that show when the UTF-8 button is clicked]

Click on "Save with Encoding" and there should be tons of encoding options. Click on "UTF-8" and it should save the file with UTF-8:

[image: Select the encoding that you want (aka UTF-8)]

UPDATE: After some researching, it looks like it's actually a zero-width space character, according to this [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/1yfnto/what_is_this_red_bulletdot_in_my_json_response_in/).

Comment: Actually, I use utf-8 encoding all the time.And what is your vscode version ?  There is no "UTF-8 with BOM" option in my drop down list .

Comment: @chenxinlong Version 1.19.2 (the latest version)

Comment: 1.19.2 too, still can't find this option. But when I go to "View -> Toggle control character ", something different shows in this part of my markdown file. You can view this pic in my question now . I can sure it's a zero-width character now, but I don't know why there is a zero-width character in my file .